# Hibernate Search: what is the purpose of static block calling Version#touch()

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm looking into a source code of Hibernate Search and stumbled into a piece of code which I don't really understand.

There is a static block calling a static method of `org.hibernate.search.engine.Version` class. I suspect it might be related to JIT but not sure how.

Could you please explain?

```
public class ImmutableSearchFactory implements ExtendedSearchIntegratorWithShareableState, WorkerBuildContext {

    static {
        Version.touch();
    }
```

Version class:

```
public final class Version {

    private Version() {
        //now allowed
    }

    public static String getVersionString() {
        return Version.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }

    static {
        LoggerFactory.make( MethodHandles.lookup() ).version( getVersionString() );
    }

    public static void touch() {
    }
}
```

Here is the link to [GihHub](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/190ca88be3b3cf4ff04cd8981d3234bf29f856a3/legacy/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/impl/ImmutableSearchFactory.java#L93)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Version` class was already loaded, `Version.touch();` won't do anything.

If the `Version` class was not loaded, `Version.touch();` will trigger the loading, which in turn will trigger the execution of the following block of static code within the `Version` class:

```
    static {
        LoggerFactory.make( MethodHandles.lookup() ).version( getVersionString() );
    }
```

... which will log the Hibernate Search version.

So the call to `Version.touch();` is only there to make sure the Hibernate Search version is logged before Hibernate Search boots.